# Wrapping anonymous types in where clauses using linq projection

Tags: c#, linq

I have recently found myself messing around with Linq Projection and was kinda wondering if there was a possibility that I could take my anonymous types and have them wrapped in different types of clauses.

So for example:

```
var projection = (from m in myData
             select new 
             {
                 // I would like to wrap my where around this instead of at the end of
                 // var projection so that i can have multiple types that run differnt
                 // linq queries
                 ServiceSelector = new
                 {
                     // I know i could have the Where() after each property, but i would 
                     // rather not have it query for each one
                     ServiceOne = m.ServiceOne,
                     ServiceTwo = m.ServiceTwo,
                     ServiceThree = m.ServiceThree
                 }
                 // end wrap of Where() here...
             }).FirstOrDefault();
             // I would also not like to have it here. Since I may have other anonymous
             // types that dont need it
```

This way I can call:

```
ServiceOne = Projection.ServiceSelector.ServiceOne;
```

But if I could call my other anonymous type that uses a `GroupBy()` instead like this:

```
GroupOne = Projection.GroupSelector.GroupOne;
```

I hope someone could provide a little bit more knowledge on this because i think it would be really neat to use in other situations.

Comment: I'm really unclear about what you want - you mean you want a single `where` clause that filters multiple properties at once?

Comment: @DStanley: yeah, so essentially whenever i call any of the service calls the `where` would be implied. But if i called a group selector the `GroupBy` would be applied.